# Injection of data in twig

Tags: php, twig, symfony4

This is the first time I come to ask for help. But here I dry and I can not find the answer to my problem anywhere.

I have just started working on the creation of a website under symfony 4. I am not yet well developed with this framework.

I have in my database a table: team that contains for each staff member:

> -the name,
>
> -first name,
>
> -profession,
>
> -particularité
>
> -image of the person.

I can display all the information without any problem on the page. But what I am asked:

Display the image and information of a person on the same page in a square orange when clicking on the image corresponding to the person.

I hope to have been clear. I myself begin to lose myself in my head by dint of reflection.

> my bug:
>  Controller "App\Controller\WhoController::index()"
>   requires that you provide a value for the "$id" argument. Either the
>   argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default
>   value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument
>   after this one.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Equipe;
use App\Repository\EquipeRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;


class WhoController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @varEquipeRepository
     */
    private $repository;

    /**
     * @varObjectManager
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EquipeRepository $repository, objectManager $em)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/who", name="who")
     * @paramEquipeRepository $repository
     */
    public function index($id, EquipeRepository $repository)
    {
        $equipes = $this->repository->findAllVisible();
        //methode pour récupérer rapidement un enregistrement find
        $equip = $this->repository->find($id);

        return $this->render('pages/who.html.twig', [
            'equipes' =>$equipes,
            'equip' => $equip,
            'controller_name' => 'WhoController',
        ]);
    }
```

```html
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Présentation{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header text-center">
        <h2>L'équipe</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="space30"></div>
    <div class="row">
        {% for equipe in equip %}
            <div class="offset-2 col-8 offset-lg-2 col-lg-8 presentation">
                <div class="pres-image offset-2 col-4 offset-lg-2 col-lg-4"><img src="{{asset('build/placeholder200x250.jpg')}}"
alt="affiche un membre de l'équipe" class="img-fluid"></div>
                <div class="contenu offset-1 col-4 offset-lg-1 col-lg-4">
                    <p class="pres-nom">Nom: {{ equip.nom }}</p>
                    <p class="pres-prenom">Prenom:{{ equip.prenom }}</p>
                    <p class="pres-profession">Profession:{{ equip.profession }}</p>
                    <p class="pres-custom">Particularité: {{ equip.custom }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        {% for equipe in equipes %}
            <div class="col-4 col-lg-3">
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    {% if equipe.imageName %}
                        <a href="{{ path('show',{ id:equipe.id }) }}">
                            <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(equipe, 'imageFile')| imagine_filter('avatar') }}" alt="card-img-top" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="card-footer text-center">
                        <h5>{{ equipe.nom }}</h5>
                        <h5>{{ equipe.prenom }}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{{ include ('pages/_footer.html.twig') }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: An indented code is more pleasant to read

Comment: `@Route("/who/{id}", name="who")` ?

Comment: What have you tried to cope with the given error message?

Answer (score 2):

In your route : @Route("/who", name="who") <- you don't have id variable.

For you, you need @Route("/who/{id}", name="who") (Thanks to [Cid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8398549/cid))